# Send Data From Two Adapter To Single Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

Two Different RecycleView Adapter Load In One Activity. Now One Of Its item Selected From RecycleView Respectively And Send There Data By Click On Button Countinue Please HelpMe Out .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjZgy.png)

Answer (score 0):

make variables static in Main class and assign values in them in adapter and use the values on continue button click.